# Javascript; using the math.random function to do a action randomly?

Tags: javascript

Well, my question is: using the math.random function to execute a another function randomly, for a example, when the math.random function chooses any number except 2, nothing will happen. When math.random function chooses 2 then the next function will execute. Making it random. Please, if you have any ideas please help me. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Use conditional branching, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_%28programming%29 once you generate a random number and need to make decision.

Answer (score 1):

The following code segment will invoke the function `doNextFunction()` if the number `2` is randomly selected from the range of `1` to `MAX`.

```
var MAX = 10;
var rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * MAX) + 1);
if (rand == 2) {
    doNextFunction();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code calls a random function in the array `arrayOfFunctions`.  This array should only have numerical indices for this to work.  Just call `randomFunction()`, this will call the function `arrayOfFunctions[random]()`

I can't think of any practical application for this sh*t, but here is the code! :-)

```
var arrayOfFunctions = Array(alert,(function(){}),Array);

function randomFunction(/*0-n args*/){
  arrayOfFunctions[Math.round(Math.random()*arrayOfFunctions.length-1)]();
}
```